# What is required for MS Project Server 2013 Reports to do anything except throw errors?

Tags: microsoft-project

I have a question with regard to Project Server Reports.

First, I provisioned the "cloud" version of Project Server, which Microsoft calls, "Project Online" via my Office 365 Portal. I was able to access it but when I click on "Reports" which takes you to the "BI Center" and attempt to open any of the reports (which are really Excel files hooked to the back end data model), there is no data. Also, only three reports are available in this Project Online environment. I was told that the "on premise" edition contains more reports out of the box. If I create a new Excel file, I can pull in data from the data model but none of the existing three reports work.

Second, I went to a service named Cloudshare which allows you to provision new environments. These are on premise style environments. And sure enough, the BI Center has more reports available out of the box which is great. Yet again, none of them work. An error is thrown that says, "We're sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request. Please try that again in a few minutes."

I've worked with SharePoint for a few years and am fully familiar with how clunky it is. I am not familiar with Project Server. What is the secret to getting even one report to run?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's Office365 and Cloudshare, this isn't really something that a sysadmin can do - unless that sysadmin happens to work for the vendor on this team. Open a support ticket.

Comment: In the Cloudshare environment, it is a series of VM's with the software installed from there. In other words, there is effectively no difference between the servers deployed from the Cloudshare template's and what I would attempt in my own on premise infrastructure. Cloudshare is nothing but a time saver.